# VBA Field Contains

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm using VBA to perform a search on a pivot field and I want to be able to do a search based on whether the field contains a portion of the string but am unsure of how to do this without checking for the whole value.  Bellow is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell
'P4 is touched
If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewPull As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Pull Code Search").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Pull Code")
If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
   NewPull = "(All)"
Else
   NewPull = Worksheets("Pull Code Search").Range("B3").Value
End If

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewPull

    If NewPull = "(All)" Then
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields(1).ShowDetail = False
    End If

pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use INSTR.

This function returns the position of first occurrence of substring in a string. You no need to loop through the whole string.

If your portion of the string (substring) exists in the actual "string", this function returns a positive value.

"**The INSTR function can only be used in VBA code in Microsoft Excel.**"

The syntax

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

More description here:

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php

Comment: FWIW `InStr` also has [a dedicated topic on Docs.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3480/searching-within-strings-for-the-presence-of-substrings#t=20161027203242050143).

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: Having trouble determining how to use that in this instance.

Comment: @WesleyKluckhohn TBH, I'm myself having trouble determining where in your code you're looking for an exact string value; when you ask vague questions, you should expect vague answers, if any at all.

Comment: please indicate the place in your code, where exactly you are looking for it. We will try to provide some idea.

Comment: The code acts a filter (which works great if they type in the exact item they're looking for). On the Pivot table it sets the value of the filter.